# Outlook 2007/2010/2013 have issue with second-level numbered bullets disappearing in inbox but not in sent

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2007/2010/2013, we get a very strange issue.  If we create a new message and all that's in it is the below 2-level ordered list and send it to ourself (or someone else, but using ourself for the sake of simplicity in this example), the second-level bullet doesn't show.

Here it is as how it should look / how it looks in the compose window and the sent folder:

[image]

That exact same message in the inbox of the person who just sent it to themselves shows as the following (note the missing "a." on the sub bullet):

[image]

If we look at the message in the sent folder it looks fine but in the inbox it doesn't.  We deleted the `Normal.dotm` and `NormalEmail.dotm` files in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates` and restarted Outlook but that didn't solve things.  We also disabled signatures but that didn't fix it.

I did a "View Source" on each message and they have surprisingly different HTML:

- Here's the inbox (i.e. broken) one: http://pastebin.com/EZcDaPDm
- Here's the sent items (i.e. good) one: http://pastebin.com/2ba4Y6Pb

We're using Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this must have something to do with either Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook (GASMO) or else the MAPI protocol.  I tried adding one of the same email accounts that had the issue and the same test worked just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding one of the same email accounts that had the issue"? I'm suffering from this as well... Is there a way to fix it without giving up on Google Apps Sync?